# Wordpress ACF repeater field conditional loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom field group for authors so that when a post or page is created, the user has the ability to add multiple authors to the post.

Under the post title, the possibilities are:

- no authors
- one author (name displays under post title)
- 2 authors (The word "and" appears between name 1 and name 2)
- and lastly, if there are more than 2 names, each name would appear on
  a separate line.

The `rep_authors` is a Repeater field.

In the repeater are two subfields, one named `po_author` which is set to page links (the author name will also be a link directed to their bio page) and the second is `text_author_other`. In the WP admin these appear under the WYSIWYG editor and allow you to add rows depending on how many authors there are. The `po_author` subfield is a drop down where you can select any of the registered authors in the admin and the `text_author_other` field allows you to manually type in a new author.

I have the code below which counts the names and echos out a basic phrase just to test the logic and that part works.

```
if ( class_exists( 'acf' ) ) :
    ?>

    <?php if ( have_rows( 'rep_authors' ) ):

        $authors = get_field( 'rep_authors' );

            $number_authors = count( $authors );

    ?>

    // Determines how to display author names based on number of authors

    <?php if ( 0 === $number_authors ) {
        echo 'There are no authors';

        }   elseif ( 1 === $number_authors ) {
                echo 'There is 1 author';
            }
                elseif ( 2 === $number_authors ) {
                echo 'There are 2 authors';
            }
                elseif ( 2 < $number_authors ) {
                echo 'More than 2 authors';
            }

        endif;

    ?>
```

The following gets the names to display one after the other on one line, but I need the way they display to be conditional as stated above.

```
    <?php $post_id = get_sub_field('po_author', false, false);?>

    <?php if( $post_id ): ?>

        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post_id); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?></a>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php the_sub_field('text_author_other');?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php

    endwhile;

    endif;

?>
```

Comment: What is the content of `rep_authors`? We need to see the data that's in that field to help you.

Comment: Hi.  rep_authors is the name of the custom field group which has one repeater field.  In the repeater are two subfields, one named po_author and the second is text_author.  In the WP admin these appear under the WYSIWYG editor and allow you to add rows depending on how many authors there are.  The po_author subfield is a drop down where you can select any of the registered authors in the admin and the text_author field allows you to manually type in a new author.  Also, keep in mind that the "There is 1 author" etc strings are purely to test the logic.  That is not what I'm trying to output.

Comment: Yes, I understand how ACF works, but we needed to know those subfields and the data they contain, otherwise we couldn't help you. And yes, I also understand you were just putting in test strings to test the logic of the count.

Comment: Do a `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $authors, TRUE) . '</pre>';` just after you define the `$authors` for each case you have (with the exception of none) and edit your question to include that.

Comment: I guess I'm just a bit confused because currently those subfields just contain test names like "John Doe" or arbitrary names that I'm entering into those fields to test them.  I'm just building out the framework and the client will be the one entering in all of the names.  Currently there is nothing in the database aside from the three test names I entered into my test post.

Comment: The echo '<pre>' . print_r( $authors, TRUE) . '</pre>'; code you suggested does print out the array, but not the name.  On the front end it looks like this for the field where I entered my own name as author:   [2] => Array
        (
            [po_author] => 
            [text_author_other] => David Kuhn
        )

Comment: It looks like it printed out your name in the `text_author_other` field. Can you make a post with a two default authors and a single custom author and post that `print_r` here?

Comment: When I select an author from the drop down in the admin, the output is like this:  [0] => Array
        (
            [po_author] => https://state.local/biographies/a-mitchell/
            [text_author_other] =>

Comment: OK. It looks like the data you're pulling from the WP users isn't correct. Is that a User field (Relationship > User)? You should be getting an array of user data from that.

Comment: The po_author field is set to page link because the name will double as a URL linking to a biography page.  Hope that answers your question.

Comment: It does, but probably not the best way to set that up - considering you're not getting the data you need to output the name correctly. You might want to consider using ACF to add a field to the User's profile that allows you to select the Bio page for that user...then use the User field on your posts to select the user. That way you can use the meta data from the user to get the bio link from the user profile. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've done. It's too difficult to parse in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I edited the initial post above,